# Accessing data related to sound from PC

Tags: c++

I have a question in regards to developing software that interacts with the computer in order to retrieve a set decibel volume from the user as specified in their speaker settings (IE If the user sets their computer volume to 45% reading that value and being able to adjust it).

Specific code is not needed as I want to understand the fundamentals of accessing system data similar to the volume example given above.

Some pseudocode of the program would run like this

```
#Begin
VolumeData = Usersetvolume as specified by their settings
If volumeData > This value -> then do something
#End
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `waveOutGetVolume` - since "__...specific code is not needed...__" I assume you can take this from here and incorporate in your code as necessary?  If this devolves into more questions, I would recommend an [edit] to your question to contain a [mcve] instead.

Comment: There is no universal way of accessing volume information. It mostly depends what operating system are you using. For Windows there is `waveOutGetVolume` winapi function, for Linux you should probably check `alsamixer` documentation.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you to the both of you